# Can we validate text alignment on a webpage/Mobile App using Selenium/Appium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Imagine that a mobile app or a web form contains 2 buttons "OK" and "Cancel". 
As per the requirement, OK should be placed to the left side of Cancel button. 
Ex:

OK     CANCEL

Is there a possible way to validate that Cancel button is present to the right side of OK button using Selenium/Appium.

Currently, I am manually validating this scenario by taking screenshot.

I am using C#.

Any suggestions or advises would be highly appreciated.

Comment: On iOS or Android?  What browser?  What display resolution?  Creating a one-size-fits-all solution will not be trivial IMHO.  You will likely have better luck with a commercial tool.

Comment: We usually perform testing on all three devices (a web browser, Android device and an IOS device.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [location](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Location.htm) property on IWebElement which returns a point value.

> Gets a Point object containing the coordinates of the upper-left corner of this element relative to the upper-left corner of the page.

So you could compare the 2 objects to see if the relative position of one element is to the left or right of another.